# Calculating the force $F$ for wich $S_2$ will be in uniform motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

> The sketch is given:
>     [image: shema]
>
> The double pulley groove of radius 
>   $r=5\;\mathrm{cm}$ and $R=10\;\mathrm{cm}$ is in rotation
>
> Two inextensible wires of negligible masses are wound around each pulley groove. Two solids $S_1$ of mass $3\;\mathrm{kg}$ and $S_2$ of mass $2\;\mathrm{kg}$ are suspended at both ends of wires. The sliding of wire on the groove is neglected.
>
> A force $F$ is exerted on the small gorge.
>
> What is the intensity of force $F$ to which the movement of the solid $S_2$ will be uniform rectilinear?

First of all the solid $S_2$ is experiencing 2 forces: $P=mg$ and $T_2$, the force of the wire.

Same for the solid $S_1$, which experiences 3 forces: $T_1$ , $R=0$ and $P=mg$.

The movement of $S_2$ is rectilinear and with Newton's second law of motion: $T+P=0$

So $T=mg$.

For $S_2$ to be in linear rectilinear movement the pulley has to be in rectilinear rotation, so:

$$M(F)+M(T_1)+M(T_2)=0$$

$$r\cdot F+R\cdot T_1+r\cdot T_2=0$$

$$\text{So: }\quad F=2T_1-T_2$$

I'm stuck here.

Comment: `What is the intensity of force F to which the movement of the solid will be uniform rectilinear` Which solid do you mean?

Comment: I mean't the solide $S_2$

Comment: Hint: Remember the subscripts. You have already found $T=mg$, but you should write it as $T_2=m_2g$ to keep it consistent. Now you just need to plug this, as well as an expression for $T_1$ that you still need to find, into the expression for $F$ you have found in the last line.

Comment: Do $S_2$ is also under the force of F undirectly ?

Comment: If you mean that $T_2$ and $F$ are combined, then yes. They are all a part of this force balance since they work on the object.

Comment: Isn't the slope or angle of inclination of the inclined plane necessary to calculate $T_1$?

Answer (score 0):

Remember subscripts! To avoid confusion. For object $S_2$ you find the expression $T=mg$. But remember to write it as $T_2=m_2g$ since there are more $T$'s and $m$'s in this system.

Now find $T_1$ in the same way as you found $T_2$. You have already explained the forces acting on $S_1$. (As @Vishwaas points out in a comment, the ramp's angle is needed here to find the right force component.)

Then just put $T_1$ and $T_2$ into the expression for $F$. That should give you an $F$ which is equal to known quantities and then you are done.

**A note on the use of terms:**

- I don't think the question really asks for the "*intensity*" of a force. It might ask for the *magnitude* or just the *force*. Intensity is something like power per area and is a quantity in another connection.
- The motion of $S_2$ will always be *rectilinear* (or just *linear*). That just means *motion along a straight line/path*, which is the only possibility it has in this setup. You might mean *uniform* which means motion with *constant speed / zero acceleration*.
- Of the same reason there is no such thing as "*rectilinear rotation*". Rotation will never be along a straight line unless you change coordinates. You rather mean *uniform rotation*.